# If function not working properly

Tags: microsoft-excel

Trying this out for the first, hope someone can assist (I'm new at formulas). I currently have the following, however 99213 is the only one that will not display.

```
=IF($B$21="Established",IF(AND($B$22>=10,$B$22<=19),"99212",""),IF($B$21="New",IF(AND($B$22>=15,$B$22<=29),"99202"),IF($B$21="Established",IF(AND($B$22>=20,$B$22<=29),"99213",""),IF($B$21="New",IF(AND($B$22>=30,$B$22<=44),"99203","")))))
```

Comment: technically there is nothing wrong with your formula, so it must be with your logic. add some sample data to the question with your expected outcomes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well its quite hard to work out what you want to do but . . . .

Nested Ifs are tricky to keep track of. You seem to have some conditions if B21 = Established and some more conditions if B21 = New so structure your Ifs accordingly
Work out the IF for 'Established' and get it working leaving a value of "XX" if B21 is not Established

Then copy and paste the entire statement (less the = sign) in place of the "xx" and edit the values for the New condition.
And I end up with something like

```
=IF($B$21="Established", IF( AND($B$22>=10,$B$22<=19),"99212",IF(AND($B$22>=20,$B$22<=29),"99213","")),IF($B$21="New", IF( AND($B$22>=15,$B$22<=29),"99202",IF(AND($B$22>=0,$B$22<=44),"99203","")),""))
```

and blank otherwise (which may or may not be helpful)

Comment: It worked! After seeing how you wrote it, made sense :) Thank you user713275

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing (using If inside another if) is called "nesting", excel only allows up to 7 nested conditions aka IFs. this includes conditions inside the AND functions.

you will need to separate your logic into multiple cells to solve the issue or rethink your logic.